# Talking to ViewController from View

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a GestureRecognizer set up in a subview to detect double-taps. When this happens, the owning ViewController should present a new ViewController. This seems to require a back-pointer from the View to its Controller.

Now that rubs me terribly the wrong way: bad MVC etc. But there must be a proper design for this. Detect the double-tap in the ViewController and then decide which subview, via the event.view value? Somehow it seems much better to have the GestureRecognizer in the subview though. What is Best Practice here?

Comment: A delegate pattern is the standard approach

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: handling of UIGestureRecognisers in UI(Sub)Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687232/ios-handling-of-uigesturerecognisers-in-uisubviews)

Comment: Why not just use the UIGestureRecognizer's addTarget:action: method and set your first controller as the target and the action being a method that sets up and presents your second viewController?

Answer (score 0):

Add a delegate protocol to the view which can report when a double tap occurs, and have the view controller conform to that protocol.

**Example**

MyView.h:

```
@protocol MyViewDelegate;

@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyViewDelegate> delegate;

// stuff here

@end

@protocol MyViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)myViewDidDoubleTap:(MyView *)myView;

@end
```

MyView.m:

```
-(void)doubleTap:(id)sender { // your double tap method called by the gesture recognizer

    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(myViewDidDoubleTap:)])
        [[self delegate] myViewDidDoubleTap:self];

}
```

Then in your view controller header (or class extension, your choice):

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyViewDelegate>
```

And where you initialize your view in the implementation file:

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
[myView setDelegate:self];
// do stuff here
```

And finally add the delegate method:

```
-(void)myViewDidDoubleTap:(UIView *)myView {

    // show your view controller here

}
```

Comment: These are about what I was thinking of. The reason I hesitate is because the subview is several levels down, and is not created by the controller directly, but by its superview, which is created by *its* superview, etc.

So I have to pass the Controller's pointer down step-by-step through several levels of initializers, store it in views that never use it just so they can pass it further down when they create subviews, etc. Awkward. But I guess that's how it is.

Comment: You can also have your view post a NSNotification and interested objects can subscribe to that